# Powershell Invoke-Command fails, Locally it works

Tags: powershell

I want to get Informations about IIS Application Pools from another Server.

This should be possible with Invoke-Command. But theres a strange behavior..

Part of the information i want to get with this command:

```
$s = "chvmes01"
$command = {Get-ItemProperty IIS:\AppPools\DefaultAppPool | Select *}
$General = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $s -ScriptBlock $command
```

But this gives me the following error:

> Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'IIS' does not exist.

When i execute this command on the local machine its working. Why? 
EDIT:
The solution was to add `Import-Module WebAdministration` to the command Variable, now its working perfectly..

The second part of the Information i want to get with the following commands:

```
$b = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $s -ScriptBlock {(Get-WebConfiguration "$appPoolPath/cpu/@limit").Value}
$a = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $s -ScriptBlock {Get-WebConfiguration "$appPoolPath/cpu/@action"}
```

Here i dont get any information nore a failure! Its the same with this command: when i execute it on my local machine it works.

Do i misunterstand Invoke-Command?

Best regards

Comment: do you have `WebAdministration module` installed on remove computer? IIS:\ drive is provided by the `WebAdministration module`, so you need to install/import that module first.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solves the first problem! i updated the code in my question.. But with the second problem it doenst help, i still get neither an error or a value back..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part of your problem. Make sure you have `WebAdministration module` installed on remote computer.
`IIS:\` drive is provided by the `WebAdministration module`, so you need to install/import that module first.

For the second part of your problem. You need to pass `arguments` for `ScriptBlock` otherwise remote computer would not know variable values.

```
$b = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $s -ScriptBlock {param($appPoolPath)(Get-WebConfiguration "$appPoolPath/cpu/@limit").Value} -ArgumentList $appPoolPath
$a = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $s -ScriptBlock {param($appPoolPath) Get-WebConfiguration "$appPoolPath/cpu/@action"} -ArgumentList $appPoolPath
```

Comment: Hei Kirill
Your solution works perfectly.. Thanks a lot for your help! the first two parts of my problem are solved! And again, i learned a lot, thank you very much for your time!